# How to split sentences into words inside map(case(key,value)=>...) in scala spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sdk, jdk1.7

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ShortTwitterAnalysis").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val text = sc.textFile("/home/tobbyj/HW1_INF553/shortTwitter.txt")
val twitter = text
  .map(_.toLowerCase)
  .map(_.replace("\t", ""))
  .map(_.replace("\"", ""))
  .map(_.replace("\n", ""))
  .map(_.replace(".", ""))
  .map(_.replaceAll("[\\p{C}]", ""))
  .map(_.split("text:")(1).split(",source:")(0))
  .zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```

Using above code I have the results as below.

```
(0,a rose by any other name would smell as sweet)
(1,a rose is a rose is a rose)
(4,rt @nba2k: the battle of two young teams tough season but one will emerge victorious who will it be? lakers or 76ers? https:\/\/tco\/nukkjq\u2026)
(2,love is like a rose the joy of all the earth)
(5,i was going to bake a cake and listen to the football flour refund?)
(3,at christmas i no more desire a rose than wish a snow in may’s new-fangled mirth)
```

However, the result I want is 'key' starting from 1 and 'value' separated into words like below for your understanding, even though I'm not sure it's going to look like below.

```
(1,(a, rose, by, any, other, name, would, smell, as, sweet))
(2,(a, rose, is, a, rose, is, a, rose))
...
```

The code I tired is

```
.map{case(key, value)=>(key+1, value.split(" "))}
```

but give me the results as below

```
(1,[Ljava.lang.String;@1dff58b)
(2,[Ljava.lang.String;@167179a3)
(3,[Ljava.lang.String;@73e8c7d7)
(4,[Ljava.lang.String;@7bffa418)
(5,[Ljava.lang.String;@2d385beb)
(6,[Ljava.lang.String;@4f1ab87e)
```

Any suggestions? After this step, I am going to map them like (1, a), (1, rose), (1, by)...(2, love), (2, rose), ....

Comment: That's because `split` returns an `Array[String]`, which is what gets printed out as the tuple value.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want to print out the values, you need to `foreach` the array.

Comment: No, I didn't mean about printing out the values. I want to separate the sentence into words and then map into (1, a) (1, rose) something like this eventually. Is my question clear? :'(

Comment: As @YuvalItzchakov pointed out your code works fine, it just doesn't print well since `toString` is not called on the `Array[String]`.

Comment: oh, I see! I used twitter.foreach(println) to print out values and still gave me the same result as above, but you mean the code is working well, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions` (documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs)) to work more easily with key-value pairs.

At that point, you can use the [`flatMapValues`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@flatMapValues[U](f:V=%3ETraversableOnce[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,U)]) method to obtain what you want; here is a minimal working example (just copy from the line containing `val tweets` if you are in the Spark console):

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc   = new SparkContext(conf)

val tweets = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "this is my first tweet", 
  "and this is my second", 
  "ok this is getting boring"))

val results =
  tweets.
    zipWithIndex.
    map(_.swap).
    flatMapValues(_.split(" "))

results.collect.foreach(println)
```

This is the output of this few lines of code:

```
(0,this)
(0,is)
(0,my)
(0,first)
(0,tweet)
(1,and)
(1,this)
(1,is)
(1,my)
(1,second)
(2,ok)
(2,this)
(2,is)
(2,getting)
(2,boring)
```

If you are interested in seeing a small example showing how to analyze a live Twitter feed with Spark Streaming you can find one [here](https://github.com/stefanobaghino/spark-twitter-stream-example).

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted!! thank you so much